# XCode Instruments does not allow the changing of target arguments

Tags: xcode, instruments

I use XCode's Instruments tool to profile a command-line C++ program, but something has stopped working since the last update when I try to change the arguments to the binary.

Previously, if I wanted to change the arguments for a binary that I wished to profile, I could go to the "Choose Target" dialog and just change the arguments.  Now, when I change the arguments, the modification seems to be ignored.  Upon reopening the "Choose Target" dialog, my modifications have disappeared, having reverted back to what they were previously.  The only way I can change the arguments is to traverse the directory structure to my binary, reselect it, then enter the args anew.  It appears that the dialog is not properly attaching to the desired binary.  Though what's odd is that it runs fine in the tool after performing my work-around.

I'm wondering if something got screwed up with the most recent update to Instruments or if I'm just doing something stupid.  All I know is that it used to work before but no longer does.